# Copy directories in python

Tags: python, directory, copy, copy-paste, shutil

When I want to copy the folders from a specific folder to another folder, I come up with error.Could you please explain to me why it has happened?

```
    import shutil
    os.chdir('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Data1')
    for subfolder in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
      if subfolder!='MyData':
        for file in os.listdir(subfolder):
          if file.endswith('.mp4'):
            name_only = file.split('.')[0]
            name=name_only+'-opencv'
            path='/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Data1/MyData/'+ subfolder
            path1='/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Data1/'+subfolder+'/'+name
    # to copy directories from a specific folder to another one.
            shutil.copytree(path1,path)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    FileExistsError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-75-642989479aae> in <cell line: 3>()
          9         path='/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Data1/MyData/'+ subfolder
         10         path1='/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Data1/'+subfolder+'/'+name
    ---> 11         shutil.copytree(path1,path)

    2 frames
    /usr/lib/python3.10/os.py in makedirs(name, mode, exist_ok)
        223             return
        224     try:
    --> 225         mkdir(name, mode)
        226     except OSError:
        227         # Cannot rely on checking for EEXIST, since the operating system

    FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Data1/MyData/Red'
```

Comment: Add the `dirs_exist_ok =True` option to allow overwriting existing directories.;

Comment: Thanks,it worked but different folders in that specific folder have the same files and with this code they will be overwitten. I mean the files from that specific folder become copied not the folders in that specific folder.

Comment: @JohnGordon Don't assume that someone did or didn't read the documentation. OP might not have English as their first language, or maybe they didn't find the documentation when looking for an answer. There are thousands of reasons someone may be asking a question about something that is explained in the docs. Please use the comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements!

Comment: @Borisonekenobi Surely we should expect expect people to read the official documentation?  This is explicitly _not_ a tutorial site.

Comment: @JohnGordon Now that you've read the first sentence of my comment, kindly read the rest and understand that that isn't the point I am trying to make.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the error:
"FileExistsError", you are trying to write a folder where the same folder exists.
You can use, same of @Barmar comment, dirs_exist_ok =True as a param in   copytree function, like:

```
shutil.copytree(path1,path, dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

Or if you don't want to override you can easily check if the folder where you want to write exist.

Comment: Yes, but now the files of that folder are copied not the folders

Comment: Is strange, with copytree you need to have files and directories recursively in the destination path (check the permission too). If you want to copy only the folders you can usa ignore param, like that:
shutil.copytree(path1, path, ignore=ignore_files,)
or param to override folders:
shutil.copytree(path1, path, ignore=ignore_files, dirs_exist_ok=True)

Comment: Well, your opinion for ignore_files was somehow good but after that the files in those folders couldn't be copied either. So I just used dirs_exist_ok=True option and removed unwanted files.